# Swift 3: Storing Class in array, can't read properties after retrieval

Tags: class, swift3, properties

I'm trying to build up a animation library and I have this object I am referring to as a MedicalCard. It's a subclass of UIView. Nothing particularly fancy about it, there's a couple of properties:

```
var isRotated: Bool = false
var idx: Int = -1
let btnToggle = UIButton()
```

In my viewcontroller I create a bunch of these by looping through a dictionary that has some stored values for each card:

```
let arrCardData = [

            ["color":UIColor.lightGray, "title":"Card 1"],
            ["color":UIColor.black, "title":"Card 2"],
            ["color":UIColor.red, "title":"Card 3"],
            ["color":UIColor.green, "title":"Card 4"]
        ]
```

and then after the instantiation I store them in an array:

```
var idx = -1
        var cardY = 50.0
        let cardW = self.view.frame.size.width

        for dictThisCard in arrCardData {

            idx = idx + 1

            let thisCard = MedicalCard()
            thisCard.backgroundColor = dictThisCard["color"] as? UIColor
            thisCard.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:cardY, width:Double(cardW), height:308.0)
            thisCard.idx = idx
            thisCard.buildCard()
            arrCards.append(thisCard)

            cardY = cardY + 100.0

            self.view.addSubview(thisCard)
        }
```

so far so good, I can add a print(thisCard.idx) and get that value in the log.

In the medical card class I have a button that starts the animation, it simply calls back to the viewcontroller through a notification which card's button was touched:

```
func toggleCard(_ myButton:UIButton) {

        //call back to move cards
        let noteName = Notification.Name("animateCards")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name:noteName, object:nil, userInfo:["idx":self.tag])


    }
```

here's where I am falling off the rails, back in the viewcontroller I get the card idx from the notification and then retrieve that card from the array. I can log it and based on the frame and memory address it's the right card:

```
func animateCards(note:Notification) -> Void {

        //get card from idx passed
        let dictUserInfo = note.userInfo
        let cardIDX = dictUserInfo!["idx"] as! Int
        let thisCard = arrCards[cardIDX];

        var angle: CGFloat = CGFloat.pi/2

        print(thisCard)

        print(arrCards[cardIDX])
}
```

here's the log:

```
<AnimationPlayground.MedicalCard: 0x7f91bdf0af10; frame = (0 50; 375 308); layer = <CALayer: 0x618000037360>>
<AnimationPlayground.MedicalCard: 0x7f91bdf0af10; frame = (0 50; 375 308); layer = <CALayer: 0x618000037360>>
```

but I can't see the properties here.

Comment: You means objects are there but you want to see their properties like color? if yes then have you tried using `description` variable of `CustomStringConvertible` protocol

Comment: I'm confused, why would I need to do that? If this was Obj-c I'd be able to read the properties without having to do anything extra.

Comment: I solved it, my error was in the array holding the subclasses - I had created it to hold <Any> when I should of created it to hold my class <MedicalCard>